# Lost on how to implement writeCharecteristic in my android code

Tags: android-bluetooth

I am using android studio's example bluetoothlegatt, which has a read function and and works completely find (it interacts with the TI keyfob I have which sends over values when pressed).

However, I have no idea how to put in writeCharecteristic because my previous attempts have failed.

Can someone help me with this? I would like to send a "1" over so that the keyfob's led lights up.

Edit: I have tried something like this

```
public void writeCharacteristic(byte[] value) { BluetoothGattService     LumService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_LUM_APP); 
if (LumService == null) { 
     System.out.println("LumService null"); return; } 
BluetoothGattCharacteristic LumChar = LumService.getCharacteristic(UUID_LUM_CHAR); 
 if (LumChar == null) { 
System.out.println("LumChar null"); return; }      
LumChar.setValue(value); boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(LumChar); 
System.out.println("Write Status: " + status);
```

This is not my code, though, just an example. I want to integrate this into the bluetoothlegatt given already, but I have had no success with it.

Comment: When you ask questions here, please ask well organized clear questions?

Comment: What would you like to to clarify?

Comment: Post what you have tried here to let others understand your question and help you..